# using php session to handle profile and backend part

Tags: php

I am making a website which has a profile and I also have designed back-end so that someone can handle the website without getting into codes.
I am having problem with sessions. I don't know how to handle multiple sessions so that they don't get mixed up.

**I keep on failing to keep track of sessions and it results to so much of error.**

My Question here is:
What are the best practices while using multiple sessions so as not to mix everything up? & 
Are session to be taken care of from the point of view of security?

Comment: use  `#about` - id selectors start with `#` while class selectors start with `.` with that being said. Don't get into the habit of using id selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in bootstrap you have 12 column if you want to center col-lg-9 firstly it should be an event number column to center means 
and you should put col-lg-2 before it

```
<div class="row">
<h1>PLACEMENT CELL</h1>
<h3>P.G.D.A.V. COLLEGE</h3>    


<div id="about" class="col-lg-2"> </div>
    <div id="about" class="col-lg-8">    
    <p>
    Pannalal Girdharlal Dayanand Anglo-Vedic (PGDAV) college, founded in the year 1957 by DAV College Managing Society draws its traditions of excellence learning from Delhi University and DAV Education Trust. This co-educational institution undertakes teaching in eleven departments offering both undergraduate and post graduate courses.    
    </p>

    <p>
    Over the years, the college has emerged as an epitome of perfection under the stewardship of its highly qualified and experienced faculty which has led to the creation of extremely talented and academically bright students in all the disciplines.    
    </p>
    <p>
    Apart from ensuring regularized learning platform, the college provides supportive vocational experience through a number of co-curricular societies and academic associations in various subjects. The college strives to provide an environment that nurtures qualities of humanism and inculcates values of team work, innovation and initiate.
    </p>    
    </div>


<div id="about" class="col-lg-2"> </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Method 1) Add `col-lg-offset-2` Like this:

```
<div id="about" class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-9">
```

[Here is Demo](https://codepen.io/ehsan97/pen/xrgaBM)

> Method 2) Add class `center` like this :

```
<div id="about" class="col-lg-9 center">
```

**And**

```
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width:75%;
}
```

[Here is Demo](https://codepen.io/ehsan97/pen/YQNJGw)

Answer (score 0):

Since the container element of your `#about` element *is* already centered, you can simply apply class `col-lg-12` instead of `col-lg-9` to `#about`, which stretches it across the whole width of its container and thereby centers it.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZyLgvX